# Add function to type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend the functionality of a type in TypeScript, and it seems to work OK so long as it's a "real" type, but if I try to declare a function for an interface that is implemented by other types in the same way, I get compiler errors.

Here's an example that works:

```
interface Set<T> {
    min(): T;
}

Set.prototype.min = function() {
    return 0;
}
```

But this one doesn't:

```
interface IterableIterator<T> {
    min(): T;
}

IterableIterator.prototype.min = function() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here I get a compiler error on the implementation `error TS2693: 'IterableIterator' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`.

What would be the correct way to define and implement a function that would apply to/be available for all interfaces implementing `IterableIterator`?

Comment: Set refers to es6's `set` and not the interface. Just as the compiler error says, you're using a type as variable.

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard I presumed as much, but how can I create a function in Typescript that would be defined for all implementations of an interface?

Comment: Interfaces arent a thing in javascript, when compiled they will removed from the source. It just promises a value to contain the defined methods or attributes. This is not how you should treat interfaces. You can however create an abstract class and implement your methods in there, or use prototypes. That's the only way to apply predefined implementation to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is transpiled to JavaSript. You can extend only JavaScript valid objects. `IterableIterator` is special feature not a valid object which can be extended. You can test that wen you write `String` to JavaScript console it response some text (means that String can be extended) but when you type `IterableIterator` it response some kind of error.

[image: Difference between Objects and features while extending it]