# How to add a function to array type in TypeScript; getting "x" is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have [the following code in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzhA2BTAdPCBzAFDAlldArvAIYBOOAXopgEQDuOAbojDQJRsDcooeALolIAzYmEQACAIKlSxAJ4AeACoA%20cQG9Q47eKE5SMPgHlSAEUQiifZSswAHUogAmOMMQEB%20AFzjMEH0ps4gC8agBGEAiIxFBsAdwgAL48INKycsgOEHzZcnYoegbGZhbEViG6BFBgfDjQNvaOLm4CPn4BQaHiEVExceJKGlo6OEK%20Ds6u7hLBs%20JVThZ4zkGOfASkUOJ8ABY4MKiI%20LviagAM4h7bezAA2mcAuuI%20UETwCTrijGTiALbuYB2FVe8Hew20QggpF832hOHEeGu%20yCmhAn0%20sIRAl%20FV2%201uOAeH3R2lG4yaUwEmBw2I4QzRJPR-z4gIqNMQv2JjJ0YUcxAA1lz0ckGdoRZ81hstszAQkRaAhFUanUtrh8EQyJRqHQoU4fIZyPh%20ga8Oh6Z8kHwETJEIQSNDguJ0Ig%20ABJG12siYHWkJxccHiAD0gfEjn%20eEW0IgYzQ6FcTogLHEO0EiCFks24h9TjlKUV1Vq0CdLvdjk9pG9uv1fEN6GNNdN5p0lq%20LGrtduT0dtxoO2I8GYrAANOIaG4BywaCOaPAmJPpwxB1PR0hiEuiQGW4OALIAoGOwfIQqGEzmSzwPiYTCDgDqVfEJqNITUt91yByABkIHRBABhYgwNQnRzK%20vr%20qKQYhmGxARoI4jRuIsbxugiYwMmqbIAGGZbDQNBykAA), and when I run it I'm getting "ves.firstOrDefault is not a function".  I would like to know why.

```
console.log(singularize("wives"));

interface Array<T> {
    firstOrDefault<T>(predicate?: (o: T) => boolean): T;
}

Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function<T>(predicate: (o: T) => boolean): T {
    if (predicate === undefined) return this.length > 0 ? this[0] : null;
    var match = null;
    for (var i in this) {
        var item = this[i];
        if (predicate(item)) {
            match = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

function singularize(word: string): string {
    let irregular = getIrregular(word);
    // remainder of logic goes here;
    return word;
}

function getIrregular(word: string): string {
    let ves: string[] = ["halves", "calves", "lives", "wives", "leaves"];

    let vesMatch = ves.firstOrDefault((vesWord: string) => 
        vesWord.toLowerCase() === vesWord);
    
    // remainder of logic goes here.
    return "";
}
```

According to [references like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862941/add-function-to-type-in-typescript), I believe the prototype pattern on `Array` should work like it does for `Set` in that SO question (which, by the way, is about extending the behavior I'm asking about to interface implementations, thus this question is not a dupe of that).

Comment: Functions are hoisted. You call `singularize`, which calls `getIrregular`, **before Array.prototype.firstOrDefault is defined**.

Comment: Move `singularize("wives")` to after you create `firstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code, where I have outlined the execution of your program with some logs:

```js
console.log("singularizing...");

console.log(singularize("wives"));

console.log("THIS NEVER RUNS");

Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function (predicate) {
    if (predicate === undefined) return this.length > 0 ? this[0] : null;
    var match = null;
    for (var i in this) {
        var item = this[i];
        if (predicate(item)) {
            match = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

function singularize(word) {
    console.log("irregularizing...");
    let irregular = getIrregular(word);
    // remainder of logic goes here;
    return word;
}

function getIrregular(word) {
    let ves = ["halves", "calves", "lives", "wives", "leaves"];

    console.log("firstOrDefaulting...");
    let vesMatch = ves.firstOrDefault((vesWord) => 
        vesWord.toLowerCase() === vesWord);
    
    // remainder of logic goes here.
    return "";
}
```

You'll notice that on the 5th line, the log never runs, and so your augmentation of `Array.prototype` is never achieved. You can fix this by moving where you call `singularize` to after the augmentation:

```js
console.log("singularizing...");

Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function (predicate) {
    if (predicate === undefined) return this.length > 0 ? this[0] : null;
    var match = null;
    for (var i in this) {
        var item = this[i];
        if (predicate(item)) {
            match = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
};

console.log(singularize("wives"));

console.log("FINALLY I CAN RUN");

function singularize(word) {
    console.log("irregularizing...");
    let irregular = getIrregular(word);
    // remainder of logic goes here;
    return word;
}

function getIrregular(word) {
    let ves = ["halves", "calves", "lives", "wives", "leaves"];

    console.log("firstOrDefaulting...");
    let vesMatch = ves.firstOrDefault((vesWord) => 
        vesWord.toLowerCase() === vesWord);
    
    // remainder of logic goes here.
    return "";
}
```